# How to check whether child form is Minimized or not?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have implemented a method named *CheckOpened*, to check whether form is opened or not.

```
private bool CheckOpened(string name)
{
    FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;

    foreach (Form frm in fc)
    {
        if (frm.Text == name)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**In same way** I want to check whether the form is minimized or not.
With that check, I want to display the minimized status in a *StatusStrip* on which the name of the minimized form will be displayed, and when user will click on the name the form, it will be shown.

How can that check be done?

Comment: Just a note about your code, I think the `||` (Or Else) should be a `&&` (And Also).

Comment: still not working i have already tried...

Comment: That wasn't a comment to answer your question, sorry. It was a remark about your current code, which will return `true` for the first form it encounters that is visible. I see that in the meantime you have changed your code, so it doesn't make any sense now.

Comment: What exactly is not working? You are asking how to determine if a form is mimimized or not. Why do the answers not work? What is happening?

Comment: The standard behavior of a minimized form (presumably you're working with an MDI application?) is ***not*** to appear on a StatusStrip. So you're probably not *actually* minimizing the forms, which explains why the answers suggesting to check the `WindowState` property don't work for you: you aren't modifying the `WindowState`. So you'll have to tell us what you're doing to "minimize" the forms to the StatusStrip, and then that'll answer your question about how to check whether they're minimized--just reverse the process.

Answer (score 1):

Use the same thecnique but querying the [WindowState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.windowstate.aspx) property:

```
private bool CheckMinimized(string name)
{
    FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;

    foreach (Form frm in fc)
    {
        if (frm.Text == name && frm.State == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: still not working...another instance of the same form is being created

Comment: Same comment as I put on the OP: the `||` should be a `&&` for the code to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a `Form` is minimized by reading the `Form.WindowState` property, which returns `FormWindowState.Normal`, `FormWindowState.Maximized` or `FormWindowState.Minimized`.